# Object not defined by Angular.js resource factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm getting a object is not defined error in an angular application I'm building.

The object that triggers the error is the 'CoffeeOrder' object in the giveMeCoffee function below. The entire source code is in [Github](https://github.com/gomesp/coffeeq).

For what I read in the [angular.js documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource), this should work (see code snippet at the bottom). But the error message is not very helpful.

```
var coffeeApp = angular.module('coffeeApp', ['ngResource']);

coffeeApp.controller('OrderController', function($scope) {

$scope.types = [
                  {name:'black', family:'coffee'}, 
                  {name:'latte', family:'coffee'}, 
                  {name:'cappuccino', family:'coffee'}, 
                  {name:'tea', family:'other'}
                  ];

  $scope.sizes = ['S', 'M', 'L'];

  $scope.giveMeCoffee = function() {
      CoffeeOrder.save({id: 1}, $scope.drink);
  }
});

coffeeApp.factory('CoffeeOrder', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/service/coffeeshop/:id/order/', {id: '@coffeeShopId'});
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's not helpful to you, but that doesn't mean it's not helpful to us. Post the exact and complete error/stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error message was exactly "CoffeeOrder is not defined", and the stack trace pointed to the line where the CoffeeOrder object is used. Your answer below worked! Guess I still have heaps to learn about angular. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoffeeOrder` is a service. A service is not a globally available object. It must be injected into other Angular components, and you didn't inject it:

```
coffeeApp.controller('OrderController', function($scope, CoffeeOrder) {
```